# Desabilitar o iCheck num checkbox

Tags: jquery

Pessoal tou utilizando o plugin iCheck para customizar os meus checkboxs da página. Tenho num formulário alguns checkbox e gostaria que o iCheck so funcionasse no checkbox que tem a classe com o nome icheck e os outros ficassem da forma original. Tem como fazer isto?

Obrigado

Comment: Forneça um exemplo do que já tem feito, incluindo o jquery e o plugin usando o StackSnippet. :)

Comment: Sim, [tem](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck).

Comment: @renan Obrigado, mas o interessante é o AP formar uma boa questão com exemplo para despertar interesse de outros usuários e também evitar problema em entendimento da questão acaso o link quebre. Posso dizer que eu e você poderíamos ter respondido a questão facilmente, mas ao meu ver a questão tem quer ser "boa" para agregar a comunidade. Outro detalhe, existem muitos plugins com nomes repetidos, colocar apenas o nome como o AP fez não é legal. :)

Comment: @Guilhermenascimento por isso que foi postado como comentário, e não como resposta.

Comment: @renan A sim, obrigado. Só queria dizer que neste momentos é melhor incentivar o autor da pergunta a fornecer detalhes relevantes :) Até mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim. 
Para iniciar o iCheck num ou mais campos faz-se através dos seletores do jQuery. Um exemplo para aplicar o iCheck a todos checkboxes e radios com o tema azul seria assim:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'
 });
```

Para selecionar somente os checkboxes e radios com a classe 'icheck' basta incluir no seletor a sua classe. Por exemplo:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].icheck, input[type="radio"].icheck').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'
 });
```

Comment: Obrigado. Era isto mesmo.